# How to select a collection of users using foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a junction table (also known as join table) with foreign keys of a users table. So first I get a collection of the foreign keys I'm interested in, and then a second query for selecting the actual records of the users.

Is there a more convenient way doing it ("at once")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.hasMany(SomethingElse);
SomethingElse.hasMany(User);

somethingElseInstance.getUsers();
```

If your foreign keys are named something other than `userId` and `somethingElseId`, you will have to do a bit of configuration, but it is still very much doable. If you need more help, please show your sequelize model definitions

Comment: It certainly does, it should accept any options that a regular `find` does

Comment: Weird. I get the error: "has no methods 'getUsers'" (And I did defined it many-to-many as you demonstrated)

Comment: You'll have to be more specific then - perhaps edit your question with a concrete example?